# How to load only active data in Django Forms

Tags: django

I have a model that is referenced to my Profile by ForeignKey. During registration, I want to load this model that is active only.

My Profile model:

```
residence_status = models.ForeignKey("residencestatus.ResidenceStatus", verbose_name="ResidenceStatus", related_name="Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My Residence Status Model:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
```

Created a separate py file to get the residence status and return as an object(Since there are a lot of models like this)

```
def get_residence_status():
    resObjs = ResidenceStatus.objects.all().filter(is_active=True)
    return resObjs
```

Then on my forms, load it all on choices:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICE = {}
        
        resObj = get_residence_status()
        for x in resObj:
            print(x)
            RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICE['id'] = x

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['residence_status'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICE)
```

On my terminal, the result if print(x) and print(RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICES) are as follows:

```
特になし
{'id': <ResidenceStatus: 特になし>}
特定技能外国人
{'id': <ResidenceStatus: 特定技能外国人>}
'高度人材
{'id': <ResidenceStatus: '高度人材>}
その他
{'id': <ResidenceStatus: その他>}
```

However, the return on my template(select) is only "d"

Answer (score 1):

choices accepts list of tuples which contain `('key', 'value')` but you're passing dict to it.

```py
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

     RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICE = [] # use list
        
     resObj = get_residence_status()
     for i, x in enumerate(resObj):
         print(x)
         RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICE.append(tuple([i+1, x]))

     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['residence_status'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RESIDENCE_STATUS_CHOICE)
```

Comment: Wow.. Thank you. I am still learning the ropes around Django. Thank you

Comment: question. Is the word tuple necessary in the code?

Comment: This helped me generate the select but when I save, it says
`Cannot assign "'3'": "ApplicantAccount.sns_name" must be a "SnsNames" instance.`

I guess it has something to do with how I generate my objects or the i+1. Any ideas?

Comment: I really can't tell about that because  it realated to ApplicantAccount and SnsName relationship and i dont see any of it in the code you showed

Comment: The relation is on models.py on top of my question